# Upgrade chaincode in chaincode devmode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am following the tutorial Chaincode for Developers - Testing Using dev mode. I have already installed and instantiated my chaincode and I want to run a new version.
I am following the instructions in the `chaincode-docker-devmode` directory of fabric samples.

I modified the chaincode and I want to install and upgrade the new version to test it, although I get an error:

`endorse upgrade proposal, get response <status:500 message:"chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0" >
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 0`

Any ideas what might me the problem?

First I install the NEW chaincode version running the command:

`peer chaincode install -p chaincodedev/chaincode/myCC -n myCC -v 5`

and then instantiate:

`peer chaincode upgrade -n myCC -v 5 -c '{"Args": []}' -C myc`

My init method doesn't have any arguments.

Comment: It seems that your chaincode have some error. Recheck your chaincode and then try to install and upgrade it.

Comment: I checked the chaincode. Looks ok. Any other possible issues?

Comment: It seems not, as per your question. You can try making a small change in chaincode and then updating the version. If it still doesn't works then you would be confirmed that there is some other issue.

Comment: Chaincode was correct. The problem was that I had to build again the chaincode, install and upgrade the new version. Then works fine.